# Toggle Shift, Control, and Alt key

Tags: vb.net, locking, toggle, shift

I have been able to toggle CAPS, NUM AND SCROLL lock using the method below but using the code below that although no error occours when I click the button nothing happens?

The code which works for caps, num and scroll

```
Private Sub imgCONTROL_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles imgCONTROL.Click
    Call keybd_event(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.ControlKey, &H14, 1, 0)
    Call keybd_event(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.ControlKey, &H14, 3, 0)
End Sub
```

The code which doesn't work, please note I have tried all variations of Alt, AltKey etc

```
Private Sub imgCONTROL_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles imgCONTROL.Click
    Call keybd_event(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Alt, &H14, 1, 0)
    Call keybd_event(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Alt, &H14, 3, 0)
End Sub
```

If anyone has a solution I would be very grateful.

Comment: well... alt or control don't have any kind of 'memory' of their states, nope ???

Comment: Biggest hint is that you don't have an LED on the keyboard that indicate their state.

Comment: Can you please add your declaration of `keybd_event` to the quesiton.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This answer is untested.  It's a quick stab at the problem.

The CAPS, NUM and SCROLL lock keys toggle when you press and release them.

The CTRL, ALT and SHIFT keys turn on when pressed and turn off when released.  Your code presses and releases the key instantly.  You need to write code to toggle the key each time the image is clicked.

```
Private Sub imageALT_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles imgALT.Click
    ' Toggle key state to pressed or released.
    Dim Static State As Boolean = False
    State = Not State
    ' Set the flags to press or release.
    Dim Flags As Integer = 1 ' KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY
    If State Then Flags = Flags Or 2 ' KEYEVENTF_KEYUP
    ' Press or release the key.
    Call keybd_event(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Alt, &H14, Flags, 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, when I go to run the program I am getting the error:


Error 1 Constant expression not representable in type 'Byte'. C:\Users\Tim\Documents\Work\Caps Lock Notifier\Caps Lock Key Version 1\Caps Lock Key Version 1\CapNotifier.vb 516 26 Caps Lock Key Version 1

Comment: in the debug console line 516 which is  
    Call keybd_event(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Alt, &H14, Flags, 0)